# dkms does not find kernel source

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, zfs, kernel-module

For days now I am trying to get ZFS-on-Linux working on Debian 7 but the module doesn't want to compile:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure zfs-dkms

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 0.6.3
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new zfs-0.6.3 DKMS files...
Building only for 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

Of course, headers and source are installed:

```
# uname -r
2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
# dpkg -l | grep 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
ii  linux-headers-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64   1                                  amd64        Header files related to Linux kernel, specifically,
ii  linux-image-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64     1                                  amd64        Linux kernel binary image for version 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
ii  linux-source-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64    1                                  all          Linux kernel source for version 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
#
```

So I am trying it manually. Still not:

```
# dkms build zfs/0.6.3 -k `uname -r` --kernelsourcedir=/usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64
Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located


ls /usr/src/linux-source-2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64 | wc -l
90
```

it contains everything (arch, block, configs, debian, ...). WTF?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a looong debug session I found that the build and source links in /lib/modules/2.6.32-openvz-042stab090.5-amd64 to /usr/src and /usr/include were missing.

Added them manually and it worked.

Everyime happy that I can work in Linux where I can at least look into the source and debug...

Comment: I had a similar problem.  I updated the kernel (yum update) and installed the zfs packages.  My kernel showed one version, while the sources showed an updated version.  Had I rebooted after the update, the zfs installation would have worked.

Your hint gave me the required clue

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I can also add one more thing: At least in Debian it seems to be important to install the linux-headers-* package **first** before upgrading the kernel (linux-image-*). That way it works for me.