# Where to copy kernel source after kernel is compiled from sources?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, linux-mint, kernel

On my linux box (Mint 17.1) I compiled the kernel from sources so that I could enable certain things that are not there by default.  The kernel compiled fine and the system boots/works just fine.  However now when I'm trying to install virtualbox, I get an error stating that the kernel source is not found.

Obviously, I don't have the source "installed" in the same way as it would be if I did something like `apt-get install linux-source`, but, obviously, I do have the source.  So the question is where should I put/copy it so that the virtualbox installer could find it?

**Update:** found the solution in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/776831/dkms-does-not-find-kernel-source).

Comment: A common convention is to store it in `/src/linux` but usually, things work if you just configure Virtualbox to look in the directory where you do have the sources.

Comment: @tripleee It's already install there.  For vbox, I know I can set `KERN_DIR`, but it still doesn't work.  I'm trying to install vbox with `apt-get` - and it seems like it's simply looking at whether the corresponding linux source package is installed.

Comment: You can tell `apt-get` to proceed even though not all dependencies are satisfied, or you can create a pseudopackage with `equivs` to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: That's the thing: there is not explicit dependency - it just fails with the message that the source is not found

Comment: Ok, found it! [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/776831/dkms-does-not-find-kernel-source) contained the right answer.